# Explain change of basis using $A' = PAP^{-1}$ in my notes.

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

[image]

Along with the attached page of notes, in which I don't understand the final two lines: pre-multiply by $\varphi'$ and use $\bf{v_j} = \varphi(\bf{e_j})$ and $\bf{v'_{i}} = \varphi'(\bf{e_i})$ to conclude that

$\bf{v_j} = \Sigma_{i}P_{ij}\bf{v'_i} \iff \bf{v'_j} = \Sigma_{i}P^{-1}_{ij}\bf{v_i}$

Then (off the page) saying we are able to calculate the entries in matrix P by expanding the unprimed basis vectors in terms of the primed basis.

Here is what I understand of it so far:

There is a general linear map $f : V \rightarrow V$ from a vector space to itself. It has the same basis for its domain and codomain.

We create, for the purposes of deriving an expression for the change of basis, two sets of basis vectors and their corresponding coordinate maps, vectors, and representing matrix.

For basis (1): $\bf{v_1,..., v_n}$ has coordintate map $ϕ(α)$ which takes in a coordinate vector $\alpha$ and spits out a vector in V. By performing elementwise multiplication with the basis vectors mentioned above. It has a representing matrix $A=\varphi^{-1}\circ f \circ \varphi$

Similarly, create another basis (2) $\bf{v_1',..., v_n'}$ for the primed world.

We insert $\varphi \circ \varphi'$ into the expression for A' in order to write $A' = PAP^{-1}$ which is apparently a useful form.

Then considering an element $\bf{v} \in V$ with coordinates $\bf{alpha} = \varphi^{-1}(\bf{v})$ in the first basis and $\bf{alpha'} = \varphi'^{-1}(\bf{v})$ in the second basis:

$\alpha' = \varphi'^{-1}(\phi(\bf{\alpha})) = P\alpha$

So P converts from unprimed to primed coordinates, and can be represented by a matrix as it is a linear map.

Then the equation:

$P\bf{e_j} = \Sigma_{i}P_{ij}\bf{e'_i}$ represents priming a standard basis vector by taking the dot product with the jth column.

Pre-multiplying by $\varphi'$ BSE converts back to coordinates in basis 2. How they have gone from here to the last line, I don't get.

Then also how is this a good way to change basis?

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't read your question but as a matter of courtesy, I think you should provide the reference (i.e. state from which book this image is from).

Comment: I would if I could William, however, these are just my lecture notes.

Comment: It seems like bad advise what is given there: $P = \varphi'^{-1} \circ \varphi,$ so you left-multiply by $\varphi'$ to reach $\varphi e_j = \sum P_{i,j} \varphi' e_i.$ All is good with the world then.

Comment: Thanks! That just about does it! 

So that means to change basis we just have to dot product $v'$ with $P^{j}$ (my course using this notation as a cheat to represent jth col) in order to obtain jth element of $v$

Comment: Hold on.. how do we use this to calculate P itself?